# Create std::wstring with date

Tags: c++

I'm looking for the go-to way to create a formatted (MySQL DATETIME compatible that is) `std::wstring` from a `std::time_t`. What I do at the moment is to create a `std::string` with `std::put_time` from a `std::stringstream`, then transform it to `std::wstring` on construction like this:

`std::wstring foo(myStdString.begin(), myStdString.end())`

But I feel this is not very elegant. Ist there an established way of doing this? Some way of retrieving in a form using wide characters all along maybe?

Comment: Why not use a `std::wostringstream` to get a `std::wstring` directly?

Comment: std::put_time doesn't seem to work with it.

Comment: You might have to specifically specify the character type, as in `std::put_time<wchar_t>(...)`. Or it might be a bug in your implementation of the standard library. What compiler are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. I'll give it a try with character type specification.

Comment: It's wrong to edit the answer into the question - it should stand as a _question_ alone.  I've rolled back so it makes sense in SO's Q&A format again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::put_time()`.  Remember that the character type is deduced from that of the 'format' argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm timestamp = *std::localtime(&t);
    static const wchar_t *format = L"It is %T.";
    std::wcout << std::put_time(&timestamp, format);
}
```

You'll probably want to write to a `std::wostringstream` rather than to `std::wcout`, but the principle is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use `localtime_s`:

```
#include <time.h>
std::wstring GetDateTime()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm timeinfo;
    wchar_t buffer[20];

    time(&rawtime);
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);

    wcsftime(buffer, 20, L"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);

    return buffer;
}
```